# shell script: [: unexpected operator

Tags: shell, sh

I have one script. Some users encounter the following problem;

```
sh: 260: [: >: unexpected operator
```

sh: 260:

```
if [ $sversion \> $scriptversion ];
```

What's the problem?

Comment: use `-gt` operator instead of `\>`

Comment: The problem is resolved. Thank you @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
if [ "$sversion" -gt "$scriptversion" ];
```